# Option Explicit - Not sure how to dim this

Tags: excel, vba

I have an existing macro that I use to format columns.  I've been using this without problems.  Now, I'm looking to learn how to use Option Explicit and I am running into a problem with defining my variable.

What should I be dim'ing Level as?  I tried Dim Level As String but that didn't work.  I'm trying to get a better understanding so any feedback would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub adviseformat()

Dim Form As Worksheet

Set Form = Sheets("Formatting")

With Form
Level = WorksheetFunction.Match("Level", .Rows("1:1"), 0)


.Columns(Level).Delete
.Columns("D:E").Delete
.Range("U:U").Value = Range("E:E").Value
.Columns("E").EntireColumn.Delete
.Columns("F:I").Delete
.Columns("I").Delete
.Columns("L").Delete
.Columns("M").Delete

Form.Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Insert
Form.Range("A1").Value = "Owner"
Form.Range("B1").Value = "Comment"
Form.Range("A1").Interior.Color = 65535
Form.Range("B1").Interior.Color = 65535
Form.Range("O1").Interior.Color = 65535

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: IIRC, its a Range, ... Though then you should be using Set on it.  Try a Variant, that should work.

Comment: @RBarryYoung : It isn't a range, it is an array : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff835873.aspx

Comment: I tried Dim Level As Variant but I get "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: @bonCodigo - I'm erroring out      `Level = WorksheetFunction.Match("Level", .Rows("1:1"), 0)`

Comment: @R3uK You are correct, it is not a Range, however, the doc you link to also says that it is not an array either, but rather a `Double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you type the WorksheetFunction.Match part, the VBA editor should pop up and give you a clue to the return type. It should say something like:

```
Match(Arg1, Arg2, [Arg3]) as Double
```

The "As Double" part tells you the return type of the Match function. This is the type you should use to declare your Level variable.

Comment: Hi Keven, thanks for responding.  I just tried setting Level As Double but I am still getting the "Run-time error '1004' "

Comment: Double is the correct data type here. Error 1004 is totally unrelated to the data type you are setting. Check https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/818808 for documentation on error 1004.

Comment: Keven, bonCodigo, R3uk I found the issue.  Keven was right, Double is the correct variable to use here.  The 1004 error I'm receiving is due to an incorrect header in my dataset.  Thank you!

Comment: @xslyx, post that [as the answer as per site rules here.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) So it helps future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff835873.aspx), I found this :

> MATCH returns the position of the matched value within lookup_array, not the value itself.
>
> For example, MATCH("b",{"a","b","c"},0) returns 2, the relative position of "b" within the array {"a","b","c"}.

So my guess is that you should use `Dim Level As Variant`

Comment: Hey R3uk, I tried Dim Level As Variant but I get Run-time error '1004'

Comment: On the `Level = ...` line?